# htaccess - rewrite path to get param

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite url `example.com/callback/` or `example.com/callback` so that PHP thinks it is`example.com/?callback`.

Trying this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} callback
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?callback [L]
```

I see `$_GET['callback'] = ""` but also `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = "/callback"`.

How to remove the path?

Comment: You mean, how to change what `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` contains? You would have to manipulate that value yourself, there is no way to get this to contain `/?callback` automatically based on your _internal_ rewrite. What the _client_ requested, is still `/callback`, and that is what you get in that property.

Comment: RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /index.php?options=$1 [L]

Comment: What is the problem with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = "/callback"`? You just need to look for existence of `$_GET['callback']`.

Comment: "so that PHP thinks it is `example.com/?callback`" - That would seem to be what your directive is already doing, and the output you are seeing suggests that that is the case and it is working as intended. So, what actually is the question here? Perhaps you need to look at `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` - which will contain just `callback` in your example.